# How to backup and restore /opt with Time Machine on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: time-machine

I have an old MacBook Pro running High Sierra. Time Machine backs up `/Users` but not `/opt`.

The Time Machine preferences let me exclude directories, but does not let me add directories that I want to back up.

How can I get Time Machine to backup `/opt` on High Sierra and how can I restore it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. That's surprising, because Time Machine backs up all folders, including `/opt`. What makes you think that `/opt` isn't getting backed up? If you plug in your Time Machine drive, open the `Backups.backupdb` folder, open the folder named like your Mac and then the folder with the most recent date, don't you see a subfolder named `opt`?

Comment: No, I do not see /opt.  I see only /Applications, /Library, /System, /tools and /Users.

Comment: No, I do not see /opt.  I see only /Applications, /Library, /System, /tools and /Users.  I also do not see /bin, /cores, /dev, /etc/, /private, /sbin, /tmp, /usr, or /var

Comment: Yes, I agree, the Finder doesn't display `/bin`, `/cores` and other "Unix" folders, giving the  (wrong) impression that they are not being backed up, but if you open Terminal, and run `ls -l`, you will see they are included. Check the screenshots in my answer below.

Comment: With a Finder window open, hit Shift-Command-dot and all hidden folders will magically appear and will also appear in the Time Machine recovery windows.  Shift-Command-dot also turns it off again.  Nevertheless @jaume's answer is correct.

Comment: @Gilby Thank you! That was the missing bit to make the answer much more useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I get Time Machine to backup `/opt` on High Sierra?

You don't need to do anything special to back it up: Time Machine backs up all folders on your Mac.

However, you may get the impression that `/opt` (and other folders like `/bin` or  `/cores`, as you mention in your comment) are not included because **the Finder hides those folders by default**:
[image]

But don't let the Finder mislead you:

- either press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to let the Finder **display all folders** (press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> again to hide them),
- or open Terminal, list the contents of the backup folder and you will see that **everything is there**:
  [image]

> How can I restore `/opt`?

Proceed as follows:

- Open a Finder window.
- Enter Time Machine.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and enter `/` to display the root folder of your drive.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to display hidden folders. You should see `/opt` now.
- Browse the timeline on the right-hand side and select the desired date.
- Select `/opt`.
- Press Restore. Note that Time Machine will probably ask whether you want to keep a copy of your current files.

Comment: If TM doesn’t show /opt then how can I restore /opt from backup?

Comment: @Nelson You can restore `/opt` as follows: open a Finder window, enter Time Machine (for example, from the Time Machine icon in the menu bar), press Shift+Command+G and type "/opt" to tell the Finder to display `/opt`. You can then select single files or directories located inside `/opt` for recovery. If you wish to restore the whole `/opt` hierarchy, type "/" instead to open the root directory, select `/opt` and press Restore.

Comment: I want to restore the whole /opt directory from the root.  If I type / and open the root directory, I cannot see opt or any of the other directories I've named before.

Comment: @Nelson You are right, typing "/" doesn't let you recover `/opt`. I've expanded my answer with information on how to restore `/opt`: enter Time Machine, press Shift+Command+G and type  "/opt", select the desired date, select all folders and press "Restore". Note that Time Machine will probably ask whether you want to keep a copy of your current files.

Comment: @Nelson: See my expanded answer: You can press Shift-Command-dot to display hidden files in the Finder, that makes restoring `/opt` much easier than my previous instructions. Could you check it out and report back?

Comment: @Nelson You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. If my post could solve your issue, I'd appreciate it if you'd mark my post as the accepted answer so that your question is displayed as solved.

Comment: Thank you for posting the Key combo short cuts!!!  
You saved me!